# Problems importing from txt file

Tags: r, import

i'm trying to import data from a .txt file as the title says.
The problem (i guess) is the structure of the file. This is the file i am trying to import:

```
"climate" <- list(
"winter temperature" = c(
4.4, 3.8, 1.8, 3.9, 0.3 ... 
),

"summer temperature"=c( 
15.4, 16.6, 15.1, 15.4, 15.2 ...
)
,
"winter precipitation"=c( 
239, 153, 184, 150, 148 ...
),

"summer precipitation"=c(
240, 85,  185, 194, 267 ...
),

"sun hours per year" =c(
1594, 1781, 1581, 1348, 1501 ...
)
)
```

What i am trying to achieve, is to have the names ("winter temp., summer temp. , ...) on the first row in my matrix, and the vectors on the second row of my matrix.

I've played around with the import wizard in RStudio, but i don't think the wizard is sufficient for this file structure.
Any advice, or a good tutorial for importing data to R?

Comment: This does not look like a "raw" data file. This is R code to create an object. Rather than importing this as data, you actually want to execute this R code to generate the climate object. `source()` can do this for you; but make sure you trust all the code in the file.

Answer (score 0):

This is an R code describing a list. You usually use

```
   source ("yourTextFile.txt")
```

But here it might not work as is because their are names with spaces, R prefers dots, and quotes. Removing quotes and space should do it.

Then making that a matrix is an other question.